# How can I get Microsoft Word 2010 to automatically quit after printing a document from a batch file?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm calling

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" /q /n myDoc.docx /mfileprintdefault /mfileexit
```

It prints and does not exit, which is a problem when called in a loop within a batch file.

Comment: If you just run it once from the command-line (not in a batch) does it exit when done?  What's the actual name of the path/file you are trying to print?  Does it have spaces?  If so, are you wrapping it in quotes?  How about if you remove the call to the print macro, will it then open and close for each as expected when in a batch?

Comment: When run from the command line, it just waits for Word to be manually closed. I can specify the file as "mydoc.docx" or mydoc.docx, and both ways respond the same way. Could it be a macro security issue, for quitting, if the printing works just fine?

Comment: /mfileexit does not seem to work by itself.

Comment: You have to call /mFileClose before calling /mFileExit. Go figure.

Comment: Close the file b4 exiting? Sounds about right.

Answer (score 7):

Please try the following argument, it worked for me.

```
/mFileCloseOrExit
```